# How to produce double column equation in two column SVJour3 LATEX2ε document?

Tags: equations, two-column, sv-classes

I am using SVJour3 LATEX2ε two column and want to span a very long equation across both columns, and to separate it from the remaining text by horizontal lines. Multicol and widetext do not work in this environment, while `\usepackage{cuted}` and strip  makes some disturbancies in the code, i.e., produces an extra '% or !' in the line below the equation, and deletes the text also below the equation. Does anybody know how to produce double column equation in two column SVJour3 LATEX2ε, without loss of the text?  The code exemple is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 
\smartqed  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{cuted} 
\setlength{\stripsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{strip}
\hrulefill
\vspace*{4pt} 
\begin{align} 
F{} &=A+B+C+D+F+G+H+A1+B1+C1+D1+F1+G1+H1 \nonumber \\
&+A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+A3+B3+C3+D3+F3+G3+H3
\end{align}
\hrulefill
\vspace*{4pt} 
\end{strip}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Or as Zarko sugested:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cuted}
\setlength{\stripsep}{0ex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{strip}
\rule[-1ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}\rule[-1ex]{1pt}{1.5ex}
\begin{align}
F   & = A+B+C+D+F+G+H+A1+B1+C1+D1+F1+G1+H1      \notag\\
    & \times\bigl(A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+\bigr)   \notag\\
    & + A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+A3+B3+C3+D3+F3+G3+H3
\end{align}
\hfill\rule[1ex]{1pt}{1.5ex}\rule[2.3ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}
\end{strip}%
\lipsum[2]
\begin{strip}
\rule[-1ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}\rule[-1ex]{1pt}{1.5ex}
\begin{align}
F   & = A+B+C+D+F+G+H+A1+B1+C1+D1+F1+G1+H1      \notag\\
    & \times\bigl(A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+\bigr)   \notag\\
    & + A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+A3+B3+C3+D3+F3+G3+H3
\end{align}
\hfill\rule[1ex]{1pt}{1.5ex}\rule[2.3ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}
\end{strip}%
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

where you can notice a missing text inbetween the equations (see Fig.)[image].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE? How this disturbance appear? Test of your MWE gives expected result (equation between two horizontal lines).

Comment: It seems that `cuted` for give expected result if are used two `strip` environments per page. This seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your problem is, but your MWE with one more equation line works fine:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cuted}
\setlength{\stripsep}{0ex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{strip}
\rule[-1ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}\rule[-1ex]{1pt}{1.5ex}
\begin{align}
F   & = A+B+C+D+F+G+H+A1+B1+C1+D1+F1+G1+H1      \notag\\
    & \times\bigl(A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+\bigr)   \notag\\
    & + A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+G2+H2+A3+B3+C3+D3+F3+G3+H3
\end{align}
\hfill\rule[1ex]{1pt}{1.5ex}\rule[2.3ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}
\end{strip}%
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]